# Change Wordpress Website Title For One Page

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to change the title that appears on my website to only affect one page and leave the rest as they are.

Obviously if I go to change the website name it does that across the whole site.

Any hints ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the `document_title_parts` filter with an `is_page()` condition.

Suppose the one page you wanted to change had ID "123" (you can also use page slug or title if preferable - see Codex). You could place the following in your (child-)theme functions.php like so :

```
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'so_change_website_name_on_particular_page' ); 

function so_change_website_name_on_particular_page( $title ) {

    //using page ID
    if ( is_page( 123 ) ) { 

        $title['site'] = 'Alternative Site Name' ;

    }

    return $title ; 

}
```

If that approach doesn't work, then you may have some funny business going on with theme or plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Forgive the lack of knowledge on this one.

The only parts I would need to change would be the page ID number & the 'Alternative Site Name' ?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for that. I have added the code to the function.php and changed the parts to fit my site.

There is no change to the site title. I have tried disabling all the plugins to check if one of them preventing it from working correctly but still nothing.

Anymore tips ?

Comment: Then it would seem there's an issue either with the implementation or with the theme. If you add to functions.php of a vanilla theme like TwentyTwenty, and it works as expected, then the problem is with your theme taking over the title tag. If not, then there's something wrong with how you're adding the code.